# Update Firebase database object with multiple uploads

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a post object that has two parts (1)photo and (2)video. In the posting flow the user selects and image, then hits next to the next screen where they select a video. Both the photo and the video are uploaded to Firebase as part of a post object. See the simple design.

wireframe design

[image]

I'm getting stuck creating the post object with both the photo url and the video url. I've tried:

1- After selecting the photo and moving to the next step, I upload the photo to Firebase storage and create the post object in the database with the photo url and an empty string for the video url.

2-Then after selecting the video, I upload the video to Firebase storage, and try to update the existing post object with the video url...

However I have not been able to update the correct post object, and don't know how I can retrieve the postByAutoID in order to update the correct post.

Here is what the database object looks like:

[image]

I tried to pass the photoURL forward to the second part of the post, but the upload and generation of the url is not complete by the time the variable gets passed.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Why can't you just create a reference to a new Firebase node, populate it with the data you want and write it? *myNewNode = myFirebase.childByAutoId()* then set the photoUrl and photoUrl children with values and write the node to Firebase?

Comment: @Jay so you'd pass the data from one viewcontroller to the next, then upload the image/video at the same time with one storageRef for the photo, another for the video; grab both urls, then write to the database? Or would you need to loop through the uploads one at a time. They have different storage locations so I'm thinking I could do both at the same time.

Comment: Depends on the use case; there's a bunch of ways to do it. Per the above comment, get a ref to the location, write out the photo, obtain it's URL and populate an object, then write out the video and populate the object, then tell the object to write its data to firebase. That object could be a struct that holds, for example, uid, photoURL and videoURL. You could also create the node in Firebase with the initial data pass the ref to other views and update the nodes within the ref as the photoURL is retrieved and then the videoURL is retrieved. It also depends on how your views are linked.

Comment: Oh - in the structure posted in your question, the child nodes under the users node (with a key of uid) have a duplicate child *userId: uid*. There's really no reason to do that since you know the uid is the parent key to the node. Doesn't hurt anything but it wont be needed. If you need some further guidance, I can post an answer that's high level conceptual so you can follow the flow. Let me know.

Answer (score 0):

With web, or JavaScript, uploads to firebase cloud storage return promises, therefore `Promise.all` an array of individual uploads.

As for swift, or IOS, you will have to push each upload (`.putData`) to memory then iterate/loop over them.

See [Upload Files on iOS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/upload-files) which provides a starting point and add your loop/iteration.

> ```
> // Data in memory
> let data = Data()
>
> // Create a reference to the file you want to upload
> let riversRef = storageRef.child("images/rivers.jpg")
>
> // Upload the file to the path "images/rivers.jpg"
> let uploadTask = riversRef.putData(data, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in
>   guard let metadata = metadata else {
>     // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
>     return
>   }
>   // Metadata contains file metadata such as size, content-type.
>   let size = metadata.size
>   // You can also access to download URL after upload.
>   riversRef.downloadURL { (url, error) in
>     guard let downloadURL = url else {
>       // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
>       return
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```